# Animated scatter plot needs to be rotated to update on Mac?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to make an animated scatter plot. Here is an MWE.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, pi

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = 20 + X**2 + Y**2 - 10*cos(2*pi*X) - 10*cos(2*pi*Y)
# surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
#                        linewidth=0, antialiased=False) #This should work uncommented

X = X.flatten()
Y = Y.flatten()
Z = Z.flatten()

points = ax.scatter(X,Y,Z)
def animate(i):
    points._offsets3d = (X,Y,Z/i)
    return points

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,range(1,10),interval=1000,blit=False,repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

I am using a macbook air with the default mac backend as far as I am aware. If you click and rotate the graph you can see that the scatterplot updates, but does not show updating by itself.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who comes to this, i changed the backend to "TKAGG" using the following at the top of the MWE:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TKAGG")
```